# How buttons without unique ids are handled differently?

Tags: javascript, html

I was just browsing and looking under the hood of web pages using google chrome's inspect option I noticed something, two of the buttons had no unique id and only the button text was different.so I was wondering how the buttons have different functions ,if there is no unique identifier for both how a click event is handled separately for both. What am I missing here.
Here's the button code

first button

`<a tabindex="0" class="jss75 jss480 jss491 jss494 jss479 undefined" role="button"><span class="jss481">FETCH QUESTIONS</span><span class="jss78"></span></a>`

second button

`<a tabindex="0" class="jss75 jss480 jss491 jss494 jss479 undefined" role="button"><span class="jss481">GO TO DASHBOARD</span><span class="jss78"></span></a>`

And why is the anchor tag used as a button like that without any links.

Comment: They most likely use the DOM manipulation API to create those elements (i.e. They create the elements using JS, add event listeners to them, and insert them into the DOM). No need for IDs then: `const btn = document.createElement('button'); btn.innerText = 'Click me'; btn.addEventListener('click', () => alert('Hi')); document.body.appendChild(btn);`

Comment: Most of all html functionalities can be reproduced with Javascript, like blex said.

Comment: There are multitude of ways of assigning events to elements, eg. you could target by ID / class / nth-child() / data-attribute etc, and you could create the Element in code and not even have to target the element.  Yes, anchor tags without links is a bit pointless, but that's what the coder has decided to do.

Comment: Based on those class names it looks like the elements are created by a reactive framework like React, Vue.js etc rather than handwritten. You don't directly access elements when you use such frameworks

Comment: so suppose if i wanted to manipulate that element by inserting my own javascript then how would i get that element.For example for autoclicking that button via javascript.

Comment: Some libraries use anchor tags as buttons (styled as a button) and use the event system rather than an `href` - for example an action on another element within a button context (say a row in a table) and interact with that contextual element.

Comment: Here is a bootstrap example of an anchor tag as a button https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#active-state

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss  An Anchor tag that looks like a button is very normal, but an anchor tag without a href is very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to select distinct elements even if they don't have a unique ID. You can either use

- a unique selector for an element (given any element on any page, it's possible to construct a unique selector string that matches only that element), OR
- from the parent element(s), navigate through the parent's `.children` to get to the child element, using the child index

For example, you can achieve the same effect with:

```js
const [fetchQuestionsAnchor, goToDashboardAnchor] = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonContainer > a');
fetchQuestionsAnchor.onclick = () => console.log('fetch questions');
goToDashboardAnchor.onclick = () => console.log('goto dashboard');
```

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <a tabindex="0" class="jss75 jss480 jss491 jss494 jss479 undefined" role="button">
    <span class="jss481">FETCH QUESTIONS</span>
    <span class="jss78"></span>
  </a>
  <a tabindex="0" class="jss75 jss480 jss491 jss494 jss479 undefined" role="button">
    <span class="jss481">GO TO DASHBOARD</span>
    <span class="jss78"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Or, without destructuring:

```js
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('.buttonContainer > a');
anchors[0].onclick = () => console.log('fetch questions');
anchors[1].onclick = () => console.log('goto dashboard');
```

```html
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <a tabindex="0" class="jss75 jss480 jss491 jss494 jss479 undefined" role="button">
    <span class="jss481">FETCH QUESTIONS</span>
    <span class="jss78"></span>
  </a>
  <a tabindex="0" class="jss75 jss480 jss491 jss494 jss479 undefined" role="button">
    <span class="jss481">GO TO DASHBOARD</span>
    <span class="jss78"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

You could also create the button with JavaScript dynamically, allowing you to attach a listener to it when you insert it into the page.

You could even uniquely identify a button from only its `textContent`, but that's much stranger.